# How to monkeypatch "GC.start"

Tags: ruby, memory, garbage-collection, metaprogramming, monkeypatching

I want to do some experiments which involve hooking into invocations of `GC.start`.

Ruby tells me `GC` is not a class when I run this:

```
class GC
  def self.start
    puts "hello"
    super
  end
end
```

But running this, Ruby tells me `GC.start` has no superclass, so I think I'm not actually hooking into the original one, but just somehow taking over that name:

```
module GC
  def self.start
    puts "hello"
    super
  end
end
GC.start
```

How can I monkeypatch `GC.start`?

Comment: [GC](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/GC.html) is a module, but since you are interested in a module method (as opposed to an instance method), you need to operate on `GC`'s singleton class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first redefine `GC::start` so we can see when it is invoked.

```
module GC
  def self.start(full_mark: true, immediate_sweep: true)
    puts "old start, full_mark: #{full_mark}, " +
      "immediate_sweep: #{immediate_sweep}"
  end
end
```

Here are two ways to obtain the desired result.

**1. Use [Module#prepend](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend) from within `GC`'s singleton class**

```
module X 
  def start(full_mark: true, immediate_sweep: true)
    puts "new start, full_mark: #{full_mark}, " +
      "immediate_sweep: #{immediate_sweep}"
    method(__method__).super_method.call(full_mark: full_mark,
      immediate_sweep: immediate_sweep)  
  end
end

module GC
  class << self
    prepend X
  end
end
```

```
GC.start(full_mark: 'cat')
new start, full_mark: cat, immediate_sweep: true
old start, full_mark: cat, immediate_sweep: true
```

Note:

```
GC.singleton_class.ancestors
  #=> [X, #<Class:GC>, Module, ...]
```

Using `Module#prepend` within `GC`'s singleton class is like `GC.extend X` except it places `X` ahead of `GC`'s singleton class among `GC`'s ancestors. See also [Method#super_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Method.html#method-i-super_method), [Object#method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-method), [Kernel#__method__](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__) and [Method#call](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Method.html#method-i-call).

Observe also that:

```
GC.singleton_class.public_send(:prepend, X)
```

can be used in place of:

```
module GC
  class << self
    prepend X
  end
end
```

**2. Use aliasing**

```
module GC
  class << self
    alias old_start start
  end

  def self.start(full_mark: true, immediate_sweep: true)
    puts "new start, full_mark: #{full_mark}, " +
      "immediate_sweep: #{immediate_sweep}"
    old_start(full_mark: full_mark, immediate_sweep: immediate_sweep)
  end
end
```

```
GC.start(full_mark: 'cat')
new start, full_mark: cat, immediate_sweep: true
old start, full_mark: cat, immediate_sweep: true
```

Aliasing was commonly used before `Module#prepend` made its debut in Ruby v2.0.